# Database to Entities in Silverlight

Tags: database, silverlight, entity-framework

I have a database with 30 to 50 tables

I would like to know how I should implement them in a silverlight project with entity framework ?

Should I put all the tables in 1 big entity (1 emdx file) or should I create an entity for each table ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean creating EDMX for every table? Why? Entity is a class mapped to a database = it will be retrieved from a database or persisted to a database. Most commonly you will have one entity per table but in some special mapping scenarios you can have more than one entity per table or entity mapped to multiple tables. EDMX represents the mapping between entities (your data model) and the database. With 30-50 you probably end with one EDMX file unless you want to modularize your application somehow.